# Is there a function to only extract/return the value of a field with Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB and want to work with it in Python which is needed for my project. I wanted to extract only the value of a specific field with Pymongo. In my case, I tried returning the name of a charging station which is saved in a database as a document with the attributes *name, standard, location, charging capacity, operator*

I only found a website which solved my problem in Mongosh by just using `db.products.findOne().collectionname`.

For a better understanding of my problem, please visit this website which describes my problem pretty good: https://database.guide/how-to-return-just-the-value-in-mongodb/

So I naturally tried using this method. But it didn't work for me with Pymongo...

```
chargers = db.chargers 

result = chargers.findOne().name
print(result)
```

I received this error as a result in the terminal after running the .py file.
[image: Terminal Error]

So my question is: Is there a method for Pymongo to return only the value of a field in a document?
E.g. the name of a product or in my case a charger.

Comment: Yes, you can do what you want with `pymongo`.  Perhaps you should start with the [`pymongo` tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) rather than the other website that does not use `pymongo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is something you can give a try:

change:

```
result = chargers.findOne().name
```

to:

```
result = chargers.findOne({"name": "the value of the document name"}, {"name"})
```

change the *"value of the document name"* to the filter, like you have a document which has a field `{name: "abc"}`, so type abc in place of *"the value of the document name"*.

then do this for clean results:

```
result = str(result["name"])
print(result)
```